# Use SkiaSharp with Maui: error for ContentView

Tags: maui, skiasharp

I have created a *Doughnut* component for Xamarin Forms. The definition of this component is like that:

```
public class Doughnut : ContentView
{
    public Doughnut() {
        var canvasView = new SKCanvasView();
        canvasView.PaintSurface += OnCanvasViewPaintSurface;
        Content = canvasView;
    }

    // ...

    private void OnCanvasViewPaintSurface(object sender, 
                 SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs args)
    {

        // ...

    }
}
```

In here I define the bindable properties and how to draw the UI to display a doughnut. This component was in the main application and I don't need to register the component in the Xamarin application.

When I try to use the same code in `Maui` the application crashes immediately at the start and the error is

> Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.Frame.NavigationFailed was unhandled.

[image]

I saw in a [post](https://www.puresourcecode.com/dotnet/maui/custom-control-for-maui-using-skiasharp/) where I have to create a library for a component and derive the component from `SKCanvasView` like

```
public class ProgressBar : SKCanvasView
{
    // ...

    protected override void OnPaintSurface(SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaintSurface(e);

        // ...
    }
}
```

and then in the `OnPaintSurface` draw the component itself. Then, create a `Registration` class to add the main component to the project like

```
public static class Registration
{
    public static MauiAppBuilder UseProgressBar(this MauiAppBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureMauiHandlers(h =>
        {
            h.AddHandler<ProgressBar, SKCanvasViewHandler>();
        });

        return builder;
    }
}
```

So, my question is: in order to create a new custom component, do I have all the time to create a library with a registration function? Can I use the `ContentView` as base for the component and then add the `SKCanvasView`?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve **Copying a blog post and claiming it is your own work is copyright infringement.** The blog post under the link *used to be* an audacious copy of **[my work](https://blog.ewers-peters.de/how-to-write-a-custom-control-for-net-maui-using-skiasharp)**. Enrico is affiliated with puresourcecode.com and apparently created that copycat post himself and now asks questions about it. I raised a flag about this yesterday and contacted puresourcecode.com about the issue as well. *In the meanwhile, the blog post has been altered.*

Comment: ok, that is obviously true. Good news is that they changed it.

Comment: I see you just use a SKCanvasView, why not just subclass a SKCanvasView instead of ContentView and avoid all the hassle.

Comment: ^^ Like @NickKovalsky says. If `Doughnut` inherits from `SKCanvasView`, then it will **automatically** use `SKCanvasViewHandler`. Any instance of Doughnut is an instance of all of its ancestors; if you don't register a handler for `Doughnut`, then it will check for a handler of its parent, `SKCanvasView`. Just do `Doughnut : SKCanvasView`, and implement `protected override void OnPaintSurface(SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs e)`. Done. Remove the code in your constructor.